# Java: Iteration over two stacks

Tags: java, iterator, stack

I wrote a program about a game simulation whereby two players,P1 and P2 in a card game are each given 10 cards numbered from 1-10. Each of them are required to arrange their cards in any order and place them face down in his pile. Then each player takes the topmost card from his pile and compares it to his opponent's. The player with the larger card wins that turn. When the players have no more cards, the one with the higher score wins the game.

I had to implement the program with `Stack` and everything works fine with the code except that the winner of the game is being wrongly displayed. Here is a sample run of where the problem lies:

**Input values for person 1:** *2,4,9,10,1,7,3,8,5,6*

**Input values for person 2:** *7,9,8,2,10,5,1,6,3,4*

**Sample output:**

*Person 1 wins!*
*Person 1 wins!*
*Person 1 wins!*
*Person 1 wins!*
*Person 1 wins!*
*Person 2 wins!*
*Person 1 wins!*
*Person 1 wins!*
*Person 2 wins!*
*Person 2 wins!*

*Player 2 is the winner!*

It had to actually display Person 1 as the winner but I don't know why Person 2 is being displayed as the winner.

Here is the code:

```
  package stacks;
  import java.util.*;
  public class Ques3 {

public static void main(String[]args){
int i,j;

    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);

    Stack<Integer> p1= new Stack<Integer>();

    Stack<Integer> p2= new Stack<Integer>();

    int count1=0;
    int count2=0;



    System.out.println("Person 1: ");

    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
    p1.push(sc.nextInt());
    }

    System.out.println("p1: "+p1);


    System.out.println("Person 2: ");
    for(j=0; j<10;j++){
        p2.push(sc.nextInt());
    }
    System.out.println("p2: "+p2);

    Iterator<Integer> it1 = p1.iterator();
    Iterator<Integer> it2=  p2.iterator(); 

    while (it1.hasNext() && it2.hasNext()) {
        if(p1.pop()>p2.pop()){
            System.out.println("Person 1 wins!");
            count1++;
            }

        else
            System.out.println("Person 2 wins!");
            count2++;

    }

    if(count1>count2){
        System.out.println("Player 1 is the winner!");}
    else
        System.out.println("Player 2 is the winner!");

  }

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add brackets around your else clause. Right now, count2++ is happening outside the else block regardless of the if condition.

```
else {
    System.out.println("Person 2 wins!");
    count2++;
}
```

Comment: ...both else clauses.

Comment: The second one doesn't matter since there is only one command being run. Nothing is being skipped.